# Best way to learn SharePoint 2013

Tags: learning

I want to learn SharePoint Development 2013 from scratch. I found many courses for SharePoint 2010 But I could not find same Essential Training for beginners in SharePoint 2013.

Is there a great book ? or Online course that is dedicated for SharePoint 2013 ?

Or should I watch both tutorials of SharePoint 2010 and 2013 ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend to use books and courses for SharePoint 2013 (some basic things are the same in 2010 and 2013, but 2013 version is a major upgrade with many new features and a lot of cool stuff).

If you alerady have basic coding skills, then this [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118495845) is great way to start. But there are other great books about SharePoint - please check out this [list](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/14579.sharepoint-2013-books-a-comprehensive-list.aspx).